# Property value in schema takes default value over defined value in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

**My Schema Definition**

```
const users = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name is mandatory'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is mandatory'],
    unique: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Format'],
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is mandatory'],
    minlength: 10,
    select: false,
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Confirming Password is mandatory'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (current) {
        return current === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords do not match',
    },
  },
  createdAt: Date,
});
```

Using this Schema I have built a controller and routing mechanism to signup for new user, From Postman I send the post request with body:

```
{
    "name": "Postman",
    "email": "postman@post.com",
    "password": "postman999",
    "passwordConfirm": "postman999",
    "role": "admin",
    "createdAt": "2020-03-12"
}
```

Following is the response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlZDUyNzExMWFhOTJjNzE5ZDI2ODQ5YSIsImlhdCI6MTU5MTAyNzQ3NCwiZXhwIjoxNTk4ODAzNDc0fQ.IgH3D6l9Gk3JmXaLE_PSp6LsZzufqKEbMT-CVSsfLSU",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "role": "user",
            "_id": "5ed527111aa92c719d26849a",
            "name": "Postman",
            "email": "postman@post.com",
            "password": "$2a$12$8dx7QwK4ShTWVuvEBV6qdOX7HA1I9TD9woDhF9W6kaBfEFaWuh2gW",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the value for ***role*** property is explicitly defined as "***admin***", default value from the schema definition is saved in the database over explicitly defined value, and ***createdAt,*** property even though a value is specified, is not saved in database at all.
When ***"required: true"*** is added to any one among ***createdAt*** or ***role*** property,  then it throws an error saying **"User validation failed: role: Path** `role` **is required."**

Comment: This may happen because I think the role is not able to pass into the mongoose schema. Please once check what are parameters are you passing to mongoose schema

Comment: @Rakeshkumarsharma, which parameters do you mean, would you please clarify?

Comment: He means if you could confirm the API middleware code that is creating the mongoose object in the first place. The `role` might not be being passed properly there.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal and  Rakesh kumar sharma, thank you both. My problem is solved.